# Progress bar from two images

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to create a progress bar from two images (empty and filled), if value is set to 30, there is image combined from 30% filled and 70% empty etc.

That's my current code

```
<ProgressBar Value="30" Height="30" Width="230" 
                     BorderThickness="0" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                     Foreground="#0A8098" Maximum="100"
                     BorderBrush="Transparent" Name="ProgressBar" Margin="137,0,147,0" >
    <ProgressBar.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image Name="PART_Track" Source="Resources/emptybar.png"  Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Rectangle Name="PART_Indicator"    HorizontalAlignment="Left">
                    <Rectangle.Fill>
                        <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/filledbar.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>
                    </Rectangle.Fill>
                </Rectangle>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ProgressBar.Template>
</ProgressBar>
```

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NnKfw.jpg) is how it's work, and [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp6z6.jpg) is how I want it to work.

Comment: Stretching is not a solution, it will decrase size, but You need the full one. I can imagine a layer on top of this (some canvas), which will hide the right side of picture, but leave there the left side (progress %)

Comment: For the incompletely filled bar, do you want to display the left side, right side or center of the filled image?

Comment: I want to display the X% width of the image when rest of image is invisible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the sake of simplicity I use colors instead of your image paths, but the idea stays the same.

Set the width of the indicator element to the width of the full track and wrap it inside a `Grid` which acts as the `PART_Indicator` control, which is responsible for clipping the progress indicator.

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Rectangle Name="PART_Track" Fill="Gray"  Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Grid Name="PART_Indicator" HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Rectangle HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="{Binding ActualWidth,ElementName=PART_Track}">
                <Rectangle.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush>
                        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="0.2"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="0.8"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Rectangle.Fill>
            </Rectangle>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: I'm total beginner in WPF, could you do it more clearly? How do I implement this to my code

Comment: There is nothing to be implemented in code. Just use your `<ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/filledbar.png" Stretch="UniformToFill"/>` instead of my `<LinearGradientBrush>` inside the `<Rectangle.Fill>` area and probably use a different stretch mode.

Comment: I meant how to connect ControlTemplate with ProgressBar

Comment: I only present the content of `<ProgressBar.Template>` from your question, since the surroundings don't need to be changed. You should recognize most parts if you compare it to your own code ;)

Comment: Oh well, that was embarrassing. Thank you so much, that was the solution I was hoping for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an easy way to achieve your exact goal (your best chance is a Grid with two columns, and the first column's width bound to the Value of the ProgressBar via a converter)

However, based on the second image you sent, you can use a green rectangle for `PART_Indicator` and set its `Opacity` and use other effects:

```
<ControlTemplate>
    <Grid>
        <Image Name="PART_Track" Source="Resources/emptybar.png"  Stretch="Fill"/>
        <Rectangle Name="PART_Indicator" Fill="DarkGreen" Opacity="0.5"   HorizontalAlignment="Left">
            <Rectangle.Effect>
                <BlurEffect  Radius="2" />
            </Rectangle.Effect>
        </Rectangle>
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

**Edit**

The first proposal. I used a Button instead of the image:

```
<ProgressBar.Template>
    <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=ProgressBar}, Converter={StaticResource conv}}"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <Image Name="PART_Track" Source="images/pic1.png"  Stretch="Fill" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <Image Source="images/pic2.png" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Stretch="UniformToFill" Width="{Binding ElementName=PART_Track, Path=ActualWidth}"   />
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</ProgressBar.Template>
```

and this is the converter:

```
public class conv : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        ProgressBar pb = value as ProgressBar;
        double av = pb.ActualWidth;
        double diff = pb.Maximum - pb.Minimum;
        return new GridLength((pb.Value / diff) * av);
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: @erexo see the edit part and let me know if anything is wrong. I check it and it works fine

Comment: I dont know if I've did everything right but the slider still seems to stretch when value is changed [img](http://i.imgur.com/FJODNzK.jpg)

Comment: The first one is great, I dont even have to use the second image

Comment: I updated the second one to work too. I used two images.

Answer (score 0):

[@grek40](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5265292/grek40) gave me an idea with their LinearGradientBrush suggestion: LinearGradientBrush can be used as OpacityMask to hide part of *filled* image

example with fixed progress value:

```
<ProgressBar Height="40" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="30">
    <ProgressBar.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <Grid>
                <Image Name="PART_Track" Source="Resources/empty.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Name="ImgIndicator" Source="Resources/filled.png" Stretch="Fill">
                    <Image.OpacityMask>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.3" Color="Black" />
                            <GradientStop Offset="0.3"/>
                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Image.OpacityMask>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ProgressBar.Template>
</ProgressBar>
```

[image: ProgressBar]

to bind offset to ProgressBar.Value I had to use MultiValueConverter, which uses Value, Minimum and Maximum to calculate Offset:

```
public class PercentageConverter: IMultiValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object[] values, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        if (values == null || values.Length != 3)
            return 0;
        if (Equals(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, values[0]) ||
            Equals(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, values[1]) ||
            Equals(DependencyProperty.UnsetValue, values[2]))
            return 0;

        double value =  (double)values[0];
        double min = (double)values[1];
        double max = (double)values[2];
        return (value - min) / (max - min);
    }

    public object[] ConvertBack(object value, Type[] targetTypes, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

```
<ProgressBar Height="40" Minimum="0" Maximum="100" Value="30">
    <ProgressBar.Template>
        <ControlTemplate>
        <Grid>
            <Image Name="PART_Track" Source="Resources/empty.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
                <Image Name="ImgIndicator" Source="Resources/filled.png" Stretch="Fill">
                    <Image.OpacityMask>
                        <LinearGradientBrush StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="1,0">
                            <GradientStop Color="Black">
                                <GradientStop.Offset>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CvtOffset}">
                                        <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="Minimum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="Maximum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </GradientStop.Offset>
                            </GradientStop>

                            <GradientStop>
                                <GradientStop.Offset>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource CvtOffset}">
                                        <Binding Path="Value" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="Minimum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                        <Binding Path="Maximum" RelativeSource="{RelativeSource TemplatedParent}"/>
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </GradientStop.Offset>
                            </GradientStop>

                        </LinearGradientBrush>
                    </Image.OpacityMask>
                </Image>
            </Grid>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ProgressBar.Template>
</ProgressBar>
```

note: Rectangle `PART_Indicator` is not used in template anymore